# Themeblvd News Scroller won't scroll

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, nivo-slider

I've made a custom Wordpress theme and when I try to activate certain plugins that do (I'm assuming) JQuery animations they don't work.

I am including the Nivo Slider which utilizes JQuery so I coded in a link to the Google hosted Jquery in the header file.

Anyway, I've tried three different "news scroller" widget plugins and none of them animate. I'm still pretty new to Wordpress, but can't tell if there is a conflict somewhere that is breaking the animation feature in the scrollers. I tried removing the Nivo Slider stuff and that didn't resolve it.

The address is www.studio-element.com/spyglass/about-us/

I know this isn't much to go on, but I would appreciate any help you can give...

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Jquery is not defined . It is inside comment so it is being ignored

your code now is this :

```
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.studio-element.com/spyglass/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.studio-element.com/spyglass/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/nivo-slider/themes/orman/orman.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.studio-element.com/spyglass/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
```

you should remove the `<!--` in the begining and the `-->` in the end .

**EDIT I** : regarding plugins conflicts - when you have such an issue (it is not seems to be the case here ) you should disable all plugins, and reactivate one by one, checking the page every time . this way you can pin point the culprit.

Comment: Oops. I commented it out for troubleshooting this problem and forgot to take it out. I was thinking when I install a plugin that uses JQuery it probably includes it automatically so maybe there was a conflict. It didn't effect my issue though. I brought (JQuery) back and still have issue. I'll try your suggestion, although it occurred with the first plugin (non-stock) I installed so there won't be many to disable... Thanks for the help though.

Comment: ok - now you have two time jQuery ... that can create a conflict . also , you are calling the initial function BEFORE the script loads . try to move all the loading to the header - or the initiation function BELOW the script itself . Also check your DIVS - a widget in wordpress will get the ID by instance .

Comment: if that does not help - change `$('#themeblvd_news_scroller_widget-2 .flexslider').flexslider ...` to `jQuery('#themeblvd_news_scroller_widget-2 .flexslider').flexslider`(

Comment: I have seen you have moved the scripts and that it worked now .. maybe you should mark this question as solved, to avoid stacking questions on the site ..

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It turns out that I had removed wp_head(); tag when I made my header template. I appreciate the help however.